# creating a word transformation graph

Tags: java, graph

I'm trying to create a graph of words from dictionary where adjacent words in the graph should agree with any of these 2 rules:
1) one of the words has one more character, and without that extra character, they are identical
2) of equal length and are identical except one letter (one-character substitution)

I wrote 2 methods to create the graph.

First one(addLadder), which uses the first rule, is working properly:
But I'm having trouble with the second method (addEq) which uses the second rule:

```
 public static void addLadder(){

        for(Map.Entry<Integer,Set<String>> e:theMap.entrySet())
        {
            int theWordLen = e . getKey ( ) ;
            Set<String>theWords = e.getValue( );
         if(theWordLen>1){
            Set<String>shorterWords = theMap.get(theWordLen-1);
            for(String s :theWords)
            {
                for(int i=0; i<theWordLen ; i++)
                {
                    String shorter = removeOneChar (s,i);
                    if(shorterWords.contains( shorter ) )
                    {
                        addEdge(s,shorter,s.length());
                        addEdge(shorter,s,s.length());
                    }
                }
            }
          } 
        }
    }





 public static void addEq(){

        for(Map.Entry<Integer,Set<String>> e:theMap.entrySet())
        {
            int theWordLen = e.getKey ( ) ;
            Set<String>theWords = e.getValue( );
            for(int i=0; i<theWordLen ; i++)
            {

                Map<String , List<String>>repMap = new TreeMap<String , List<String>>();
                List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
                for(String w:theWords  )
                {
                    String shorter = removeOneChar(w,i);
                    myList.add(shorter);
                    repMap.put(w, myList);

                }

    }
}
```

}

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Your question is itself a question/

Comment: How can i modify addEq so that it complies with the second rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the words character per character as long as the edit distance is 1:
e.g.:

```
private boolean ruleTwo (String s1, String s2)
{
    if (s1.length() != s2.length())
        return false;


    int different = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<s1.length() && different <= 1; i++)
    {
        if (s1.charAt(i) != s2.charAt(i))
            different ++;
    }

    return different == 1;
}
```